# .hpp files not running in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I was trying to create a .hpp file in vscode, but when I tried running it I was told it was not compatible with my system. However, I am able to use and run .cpp files just fine.

TreeNode.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.

```
class TreeNode{
    public:
        char value;
        char left;
        char right;
        TreeNode(char val){
                value = val;
                
        }
};
```

Comment: You can run neither `.hpp` nor `.cpp` files. You can only compile and link them and run the created executable. Please show us how you compile your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you are doing so that we can help you. We need details on how you compiled your code.

Comment: I use the code runner extension and MinGW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*.hpp` are the header files without `main()` function, whereas `*.cpp` files containing `main()` function are for compiling through (`gcc` or `clang`). To test out your `*.hpp` files you need to include it in `*.cpp` file.

```cpp
#include "./my_header_file.hpp"
```

Always remember, `main()` is the entry of your program, it should exist.

---

Also, I think your class `TreeNode` isn't correct instead of:

```cpp
char left;
char right;
```

It should be:

```cpp
TreeNode *left; // allocate on heap-memory using `new` operator
TreeNode *right; // allocate on heap-memory using `new` operator
```